# Apc_fetch undefined in CLI

Tags: php, caching, command-line, command-line-interface, apc

I'm having some trouble with APC in the command line -- the script I run tells me apc_fetch is undefined. If I do function_exists('apc_fetch'); outside the command line it outputs true but if I do php --rf apc_fetch it tells me it doesn't exist.

I have APC enabled (enabled & enable_cli) in php.ini and it shows up in my phpinfo. The APC status page shows me the following info:

```
apc.cache_by_default    1
apc.canonicalize    1
apc.coredump_unmap  0
apc.enable_cli  1
apc.enabled 1
apc.file_md5    0
apc.file_update_protection  2
apc.filters 
apc.gc_ttl  3600
apc.include_once_override   0
apc.lazy_classes    0
apc.lazy_functions  0
apc.max_file_size   1M
apc.num_files_hint  1000
apc.preload_path    
apc.report_autofilter   0
apc.rfc1867 0
apc.rfc1867_freq    0
apc.rfc1867_name    APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix  upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl 3600
apc.serializer  default
apc.shm_segments    1
apc.shm_size    32M
apc.slam_defense    1
apc.stat    1
apc.stat_ctime  0
apc.ttl 0
apc.use_request_time    1
apc.user_entries_hint   4096
apc.user_ttl    0
apc.write_lock  1
```

What am I doing wrong? (I'm trying to use Doctrine's schema generator, with CodeIgniter on WAMP)

Comment: What `php -i |grep -i apc` shows? CLI and apache-driven php are always have different php.ini's

Comment: @zerkms -- There doesn't seem to be any reference to APC when I do `php -i`. What could be doing this? I've looked at the php.ini files (Apache and PHP) and they both have `apc.enabled = 1` and `apc.enable_cli = 1`. What do you suggest?

Comment: check the output php -i to *make real sure* you know what ini file(s) its using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CLI and Apache php use different configs

Answer (score 1):

Zerkms comment helped me figure out what was wrong. I had APC enabled in both php.ini files but I was only loading the extension in Apache. I loaded the extension in PHP's php.ini as well and it worked. Thanks